# Ruby Threads: progress bar during copy

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm pretty new to Ruby Threads, so could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'zip'
require 'rubygems'
require 'progressbar'

oraclePath = "\\\\server\\Oracle Client\\Oracle_11gR2\\win64_11gR2_client.zip"

begin
tmpDir = Dir.mktmpdir("ora-")

progress = Thread.new(){
  Thread.current[:name] = "FileProgress"

  sourceFileSize = File.size("#{oraclePath}")
  batch_bytes = ( in_size / 100 ).ceil
  total       = 0
  p_bar       = ProgressBar.new('Copying', 100)

  buffer      = "#{oraclePath}".sysread(batch_bytes)
  while total < sourceFileSize do
    "#{tmpDir}".syswrite(buffer)
    p_bar.inc
    total += batch_bytes
    if (sourceFileSize - total) < batch_bytes
      batch_bytes = (sourceFileSize - total)
    end
    buffer = "#{oraclePath}".sysread(batch_bytes)
  end
  p_bar.finish
}

progress.run

puts "#{tmpDir}"
FileUtils.cp_r("#{oraclePath}","#{tmpDir}")
Zip::File.open("#{tmpDir}/win64_11gR2_client.zip") do |zipfile|
  `unzip -j #{zipfile} -d #{dir}`
  #zipfile.each do |file|
  #zipfile.extract(file, "#{tmpDir}")
  #end
end

ensure
  # remove the temp directories
  FileUtils.remove_entry_secure tmpDir
end
```

The copying works, but the thread doesn't - I can't even step into it; it just skips it entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If the copy works, then the thread is running.  Why do you think it's not?

Comment: I'm referring to the `progress` thread

Comment: Yes, of course, but that doesn't answer my question.  I've attempted to answer given the information I have.  Let me know if that doesn't help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Something still isn't making sense.  You've said the copy works but the thread doesn't.  Can you explain that a bit more, since the thread is what's doing the copying?

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby Thread will start running the moment it's instantiated with `Thread.new`, so in your example the copy begins immediately and the line `progress.run` isn't necessary.

You would only need to call `run` if the thread itself had stopped (i.e. called `stop` on itself while waiting for further instructions).

As reference, you can find more information here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Thread.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what I'm seeing then. I have breakpoints in my new thread, but they never get hit. It's like when I step *into* the thread, it actually just skips it.

Comment: Could it be that your editor doesn't support walking into Threads (they are a separate process, afterall)?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of RubyMine - I haven't checked, but I assume since it's the industry standard IDE that it supports threading?

Comment: What line, _exactly_, are you trying to step into?  `progress.run` doesn't actually do anything, as I've said.